# Last Login Date to Application

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am looking for an API to find the user's last login date to a particular application. Not sure if it exists, please let me know your thoughts on getting this information through API calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last date the user was authenticated to *any* application on the [User profile](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#get-user-with-id):

```
GET https://dev-12345.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users/xyz

{
    "id": "xyz",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "created": "2017-02-22T02:33:02.000Z",
    "activated": null,
    "statusChanged": "2017-02-22T17:50:43.000Z",
    "lastLogin": "2017-09-28T16:19:57.000Z",
    "lastUpdated": "2017-08-08T20:11:46.000Z",
    "passwordChanged": "2017-02-22T17:50:43.000Z",
    "profile": {
        "lastName": "Barbettini",
        "firstName": "Nathanael",
    // ...
}
```

The `lastLogin` field contains the timestamp of the last time the user logged in.

This isn't tracked on a per-app basis, though. You can get the app-specific [App User](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps.html#get-assigned-user-for-application):

```
GET https://dev-12345.oktapreview.com/api/v1/apps/abc/users/

{
    "created": "2017-09-22T00:54:49.000Z",
    "lastUpdated": "2017-09-22T00:54:49.000Z",
    "scope": "GROUP",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "statusChanged": "2017-09-22T00:54:49.000Z",
    "passwordChanged": null,
    "syncState": "DISABLED",
    "profile": {
        "zoneinfo": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "region": null,
    // ...
}
```

But it doesn't have `lastLogin`. One way you could solve this is by saving a timestamp in the App User profile in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [filters](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/design_principles#filtering) to specify which logs do you want from the system logs API endpoint, limit the answer to 1, set the response order to start from the most recent ones, and user filters again to filter for your user.

So, you need to filter the request using the following filters:

- *actor.alternateId*: which identifies the user, in my case the pattern "username@" is enough
- *event_type*: this one should be user.authentication.sso which means that the user SSO to an app (any of the ones available for that user)
- *outcome.result*: success, which means that the user successfully SSO to the app

Example query would be something like this:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: SSWS super-secret-token-here" -H "Accept: application/json" "https://<your.domain.here.com>/api/v1/logs?until=2018-07-17T11%3A30%3A55.664541&limit=1&sortOrder=DESCENDING&filter=event_type+eq+%22user.authentication.sso%22+and+outcome.result+eq+%22SUCCESS%22+and+actor.alternateId+sw+%22<user name here>%40%22"
```

Remember to replace the token, the URL and the  before testing this query.
Also, remember that this example is URL encoded, so this is why it looks so weird.